# Installing poco library

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

im trying to install the [poco library](http://pocoproject.org) for visual c++ 2008 but when I type this command

buildwin.cmd 90

I get the following error

"'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

The readme file says there is an alternate way to install poco from visual studio itself but i don't quite know how to do that either.

any pointers what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the projects by opening the solution files in Visual Studio and build them from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestion worked, I now have everything installed but when i run a program it says dll missing, I have set the paths for my include and lib files in the tools->options->vc++ directories,

could you tell me what I need to do to make VS know how to find the dll's? i know the dll's folder location.

Comment: When loading DLLs I usually add the dir containing the dll files to my system or user PATH variable. However, for Poco I always link statically.

Comment: I added the folder to my path and it now works, Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your shell environment doesn't have all the needed paths. Have you tried using the VS Command Prompt? If not,just click the link in the Start Menu VS entry that opens cmd.exe with some additional environmental setup.

Comment: I tried it in the visual studio command prompt but got the following 

"debug_shared
released_shared
debug_static
release_static
FINDSTR: Cannot open components
FINDSTR: Cannot open components"

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I though it might help anyone in the future. For jack the lesser's reply to Adam Wright's comment, I had the same "cannot open components" issue and it was caused by not being in the exact directory as buildwin. I was targeting it from where the VS command line dropped me off but once I changed directories it proceeded to build.